# getting error " Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » "

Tags: reactjs

```
F:\\React tutoria;\\tut-3\\my-app\>npm run build

my-app@0.1.0 build
react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » F:\\React tutoria;\\tut-3\\my-app\\node_modules\\eslint-config-react-app\\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\\Users\\GAGAN BISHT\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\node_modules\\eslint-config-react-app\\base.js".
```

I tried to save package.json file again and again but it doesn't work

Comment: what does `npm ls react` give you?

Comment: PS F:\React tutoria;\tut-3\my-app> npm ls
my-app@0.1.0 F:\React tutoria;\tut-3\my-app
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.16.4
├── @testing-library/react@12.1.4
├── @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0
├── react-dom@18.0.0
├── react-scripts@5.0.0
├── react@18.0.0
└── web-vitals@2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

the solution for that is simply go to package.json file and delete the eslint-config

"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
]
},
this one